# Centering and correct element (div) order

Tags: css, html, css-float

Please forgive my lack of design knowledge but I am confused by a bit of div positioning.  I have a header div. Within that header I want two divs, one for the logo, and below that another for some content.  I have labeled them logo and card respectively.  However, when I try to put them both into the html, calling them in proper order, the card div simply lays atop the logo div rather than beneath it.  I have tried using pretty much every variation of "clear: xxx" both in the css and inline within the html but they have no effect whatsoever.  Can someone explain why this isn't working?  Posting relevant css and html below.

```
#header {
    height:440px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background:url(/assets/header-tail.gif) 0 0 repeat-x #f7f7f7
    }
#header .logo {
    position:absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -198px;
}
#header .card {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -500px;
    height: 367px;
    width: 999px;
    background:url(/assets/hback.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    clear: left;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<div class="logo"><%= link_to image_tag("srlogo.png",alt:"Logo"), 'index.html' %></div>
<div class="card">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:  So yes, clearly I am an idiot for trying to use "clear" with no floated elements.  I understand that now.  So how do I get one division below, rather than on top of, the other?

Comment: clear is used on floated elements, it appears you have none there...

Comment: Is this necessary to use `absolute` position ?

Comment: Absolutely-positioned elements don't follow "float" rules. They have their own layout context.

Comment: @Sheikh:  I am using absolute positioning as a way to center the divs on the page.

Comment: Use `text-align:center` or `margin:auto` when div has a fixed width.

Comment: Again, none of this really solves my problem does it?  I still have one div sitting atop the other.  I've just used a different method of centering them.  Or is there more to the story?

Comment: Do you know the width of the `logo` div before hand?

Comment: Added a jsFiddle for you.  Is that what you want?  the image comes before the text and is centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of all your absolute positioning.  It's rubbish.

http://jsfiddle.net/2BpfF/1/

If you want the `.logo` DIV to be centered on the page and you know it's width you can do this:

```css
#wrapper {
     width: 999px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    height:416px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    }
#header .logo {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 333px;
}
#header .card {
     background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/999/367/);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     height: 367px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="header">
          <div class="logo"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/333/49/" /></div>
          <div class="card">Some text here</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

`margin: 0 auto;` adds 0px margins to the top and bottom of the DIV while calculating the left and right amount for you so it will center.  This will only work with a known width.

It seems like you want to center everything.  So I would start with a `wrapper` DIV and center that.  I did this with `#wrapper`.

Remember that source order matters and that by default your `.logo` DIV will display before your `.card` DIV without any CSS.

You can also remove the `width: 100%;` from your `#header` DIV as all DIVs by default are block level elements.  Block level elements always take up the full width of their containing element unless told otherwise.

As for the opacity of the background image I think the best solution would to do this for your image file and not with CSS as I don't think opacity is very versatile yet.  What I mean my this is if you set `opacity: 0.5;` to a DIV, then everything in that div is 50% opaque.  I'm not a guru on opacity so you'd have to dig into that a little deeper.  But I would just set the opacity in your image editor to 50% and output a `PNG` file so the alpha(opacity) chanels will be there.  `JPG` files do not have alpha channels for transparency.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle.  It helps me understand how poorly I am communicating my problem, and I say that in all seriousness.  what I have is a logo div with a logo that is only 333x49.  I would like that at the top of the page.  Then, below that, another division (card) that is 999x367 with a background image that is also 999x367 ( 50% opacity ).  The text would be contained within the "card" div, and as such be contained within that 999x367.  What I am getting so far is...

Comment: when I use any other method of centering the divs I either get the card div atop, and thus blocking out, the logo div, or the card div gets flung to the far left hand margin of the screen and the background image is not shown at all.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that what I need first is a giant div with a width of, say, 1000px, to contain the entire page so that I don't have things randomly drifting to the far left of the screen?

Comment: Without a set width + centering or some margins, things will naturally want to start at the left of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have any floated elements, so [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) has absolutely no effect.
2. [Absolute positioning removes the element from the document flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), so floating and clearing will have no effects on such positioned elements, since floating adjusts the element within its content flow.

Comment: So perhaps you could suggest a way to get the card div below the logo div?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `absolute` positioning. Same thing you can achieve using something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/PNzZj/1/) :

```
#header {
    height:440px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background:url(/assets/header-tail.gif) 0 0 repeat-x #f7f7f7
}
#header .logo {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
}
#header .card {
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 367px;
    width: 999px;
    background:url(/assets/hback.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This did keep the logo centered.  However, the background image of .card disappeared entirely and the "some text here" was flung to the far left edge of the screen.  I'm wondering if I should put the text-align: center within the #header block rather than just with the .logo block.

Comment: You may try, I just gave an example of what you can use, but you didn't ask exactly what is your expectation.